# Mongoose FindAndUpdate elements inside an object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

With an object like this:

```
{
  _id: 'somehting',
  foo1: 'bar1',
  foo2: 'bar2'
}
```

If I do:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: something }, {foo2: 'new value'});
```

foo2 will be modified and foo1 will remain intact since Mongoose uses $set internally as far as I know.

What if the object is instead like this:

```
{
  _id: 'somehting',
  meta: {
        foo1: 'bar1',
        foo2: 'bar2'
  }
}
```

In this case, doing a:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: something }, {meta: { foo2: 'new value'}});
```

Will overwrite completely *meta* leaving only *foo2*.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior as when the data is in the root of the object and not in a sub-object?

I know I can first make a find, take the *meta* object a merge it with the new data, and then make a save, but I will like to make it in one query with findAndUpdate. Is it possible?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation: `{"meta.foo2": "new value"}`

Comment: @AlexBlex I know this, but the thing is the payload comes from an API, not in dot notation. Sometimes it can be  { meta: { foo1: 123 }}, other time can be { meta: { foo2: 222, foo1: 321 }} and so. If I pass those payloads directly to the findAndUpdate it will overwrite completely meta. I suppose I can create a function to  convert the object to dot notation, but it feels like I am reinventing the wheel

Comment: no, you are not. The reason for having dot-notation syntax is to distinguish cases where you actually need to replace whole "meta" with { foo2: 'new value'} alone.

Comment: @AlexBlex I did not explain my self correctly when I said I feel like reinventing the wheel, I was referring to the fact of building a function to convert from regular notation to dot notation and not to the fact dot notation itself is required. I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve my goal using Mongoose without any external function

Comment: no there are not. These are 2 different syntaxes to achieve 2 different results. The fact that your "payload comes from an API" and it's "not in dot notation." is specific to your case and it's your job to write the compatibility layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to set the specific value of an object in MongoDB query.